# Dropdown does not bind properly on ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In angularjs, Instead of binding data to dropdown at initially(for eg.: **Assigning values** through controller **$scope.items**), I need to bind dropdown at dropdown click event.

I tired with **ng-click** event but it doesn't work properly, consider the code

**My Problem: when i execute my code**

Step-1 : **First time** click the dropdown it **does not show the data list**.

Step-2 : **Second time** click the dropdown **now it shows the data list**.

am  new to angularJS, i don't know how to resolve this simple issue.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

            myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
                var countryds = [
                    { 'name': 'India' },
                    { 'name': 'Pakistan' },
                    { 'name': 'Afganistan' }
                ];
                $scope.my = { favorite: '' };
                $scope.items = '';
                $scope.binddropdown = function (element) {
                    element.items = countryds;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <select ng-model="my.favorite" ng-options="i.name for i in items" ng-click="binddropdown(this)">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/orveo3ao/

Comment: please notice, on first click of dropdown doesnot populate list item that is the problem

Comment: not sure what you mean. It does populate the first time I click on the dropdown.

Comment: Generally, while click the dropdown then dropdown list item appear but my problem is while click the dropdown dropdown list item not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in the bottom of the page, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-model="my.favorite" ng-options="i.name for i in items" ng-click="binddropdown(this)">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.countries = [
                { 'name': 'India' },
                { 'name': 'Pakistan' },
                { 'name': 'Afganistan' }
            ];
            $scope.my = { favorite: '' };            
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Because you are running Angular code and binding elements which at that point aren't even created in the DOM. Probably because of some caching mechanisms - the code works the 2nd time around, but it's not how you want to do it.

EDIT: I updated the script.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick support, when i click dropdown first time need to show data list.. Even i tired with your code i get the same problem.

Comment: According to my scenario, Instead of binding data to dropdown at initially(for eg.: Assigning values through controller $scope.items), I need to bind dropdown at dropdown click event.

Comment: Like so then? http://jsfiddle.net/358uqccy/2/ - or use `ng-mousedown` ( in stead of `ng-click` ) if you want the countries to show up immediately on the first click.

Comment: while using ng mouse event works fine. Is there any other options other than ng-mouse event like(ng-mouseenter, ng-mouseup, ng-mousedown). My idea is "load data to dropdown" at page load took some amount time to avoid this, through click event whether it possible means my page loaded quickly.

Comment: Yes, there are more events ( Google it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter ). Now about page load times - if you are getting your dropdown form somewhere else - you are not going to save a lot of time by posponing that: it's already async. If you are worried about the time it takes to bind the list - I wouldn't now, but with the current JS engines in the modern browsers I think it will be less significant then the network latency for getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very long since your question is posted ! But found an answer I changed `ng-click` with `ng-focus` and its showing in first click

`ng-focus` is a nice solution since it works with keyboard events also

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
      var countries = [{
          'name': 'India'
      }, {
          'name': 'Pakistan'
      }, {
          'name': 'Afganistan'
      }];
      
      $scope.countries = [];      
      $scope.my = {
          favorite: ''
      };
      $scope.bindList = function() {
          $scope.countries = countries;
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="my.favorite" ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-focus="bindList()">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select> <pre>
{{ my | json }}
    </pre>

</div>
```